# Add ' http:' to innerHTML of img src

Tags: image, innerhtml

how do I add 'http:' at the beginning of img src in innerHTML? Images are not fetched properly because img src is like this "//upload/image.jpg"

Thanks in advance for any suggestions you might have.

Answer (score 0):

src is an attribute of the img tag, so you wouldn't use innerHTML.

You can do something like:

```
var myImage = document.getElementById('myImage');
myImage.src = 'http:' + myImage.src;
```

Comment: I should have been more specific. There's this js app which gets articles off wikipedia, but thumbnails are all blank. In the emulator when I pass over an image the log reads for instance: element text= <img alt="Peter Heywood" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d2/HEYWD.JPG/100px-HEYWD.JPG" and I suppose the 'culprit' is this part of the js code: alert("element text= " + UIContents.allElements[UIContents.currentSelectedElement].innerHTML);

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it doesn't work. Thanks, anyway. @dejuknow